# Firebase Cloud Storage Pricing - What is considered "GB downloaded" and "GB transferred"

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

With [Firebase Cloud Storage Pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing), it says the price of "GB downloaded", "Upload operations", "download operations", then in the Blaze plan calculator it says "GB Transferred" and "Operations (uploads & downloads)".

With "GB downloaded" and "download operations", does it include when you view an image from within a mobile app via a url to an object in the bucket? Or only when you download the image to save the file on the device?

I have the same question for "GB transferred" - would viewing an image from a url within the mobile app count as GB transferred, and be whatever the size of the image is?

[image]

Comment: Answer to the first part is below. I'm not aware of a "transfer" charge, and don't immediately see anything related to Firebase in the page you linked. Can you clarify that part of your question, provide a link to the relevant Firebase docs, or maybe elaborate on the use-case where "GB transferred" might come into play?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Oh dear, I linked the completely wrong page, sorry! Try a copy paste of GB Transferred in the new url which I actually meant to use. My bad!

Comment: I don't see "GB Transferred" there either. The only "transfer" is for Hosting, which is unrelated to charges for Storage. Can you maybe pull the information you're referring to, and include it as a quote in your question too?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I see it in the Blaze plan calculator near the bottom of the page, I have just added the snapshot. Cheers

Comment: Ah got it. Thanks for sticking with me. :)   That should indeed be "GB downloaded", same as in the table. I've filed a bug to get it updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With "GB downloaded" and "download operations", does it include when you view an image from within a mobile app via a url to an object in the bucket?

Accessing the file through the download URL also read the data for that file from the system, so are also charged as "GB downloaded" and "download operations".

The mention on "GB transferred" in the pricing calculator for Storage is a mistake, and should also be "GB downloaded". I've filed an internal bug to get that updated.

Comment: I am still confused about pricing between Google Cloud Storage vs Firebase Cloud Storage. Does FCS charges $0.026/GB in all regions it doesn’t matter which regions?? Also GCS also offers free egress in some regions up to 100GB does Firebase charge you not matter what region?

Comment: The default bucket that Firebase creates follows the old (and indeed much simpler) App Engine pricing scheme. All other buckets that you create in the project follow regular Google Cloud Storage (GCS) pricing. So if you want to make use of the region-specific aspects of GCS pricing, be sure to immediately create a regular GCS bucket, associate that with Firebase in the console, and use that for all your needs.

Comment: Good then its nice to say I will create a bucket in GCS first.